# Validación formularios Spring

Tags: spring

Intento hacer una serie de validaciones sobre un formulario con hibernate validator en Spring, pero no consigo ver por qué no me realiza esas comprobaciones correctamente. Muestro aquí el código:

```
public class Alumno {

@NotNull
@Size(min=2, message=" Campo requerido")
private String nombre;

@NotNull
@Size(min=2, message=" Campo requerido")
private String apellido;

@Min(value=10, message="Edad minima = 10")
@Max(value=100, message="Edad máxima= 100")
private int edad;

private String optativa;

private String Descuento;

private String provincia;

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}
public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public String getProvincia() {
    return provincia;
}
public void setProvincia(String provincia) {
    this.provincia = provincia;
}
public String getDescuento() {
    return Descuento;
}
public void setDescuento(String descuento) {
    Descuento = descuento;
}
public String getOptativa() {
    return optativa;
}
public void setOptativa(String optativa) {
    this.optativa = optativa;
}
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}
public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

}
```

Esta es la clase y este el controlador:

```
@Controller

@RequestMapping("/alumno")

public class AlumnoController {

@RequestMapping("/muestraFormulario")
public String muestraFormulario(Model modelo) {
    
    Alumno elAlumno = new Alumno();
    
    modelo.addAttribute("elAlumno", elAlumno);
    
    return "alumnoRegistroFormulario";
}

@RequestMapping("/procesarFormulario")
public String procesarFormulario(@Valid @ModelAttribute("elAlumno") Alumno elAlumno, BindingResult resultadoValidacion) {
    
    if (resultadoValidacion.hasErrors()){
        return "alumnoRegistroFormulario";
    }else {
        return "confirmacionRegistroAlumno";
    }
}
}
```

Pues bien, cuando llega la parte donde debería guardar los errores de la validación en `BindingResult`,  `resultadoValidacion` no lo hace. Dejando vacíos los campos del formulario no recoge ningún error y `resultadoValidacion.haserrors()` es `false`.

Comment: Según [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) de `@Size`, el valor null es un valor válido. Estoy casi seguro que tu problema radica en que no estás enviando el formulario de manera correcta a tu controlador y por tanto tus datos llegan null. ¿Podrías por favor adjuntar el código del formulario? Realiza un System.out.print(elAlumno) en tu método procesar formulario a ver que te está llegando.

Comment: Lo conseguí solucionar, al final era problema de librerías, estaba importando unas librerías erróneas para las anotaciones, es lo que tiene estar importandolas a mano... Muchas gracias de todas formas